# Django issue with import models

Tags: python, django

I am very new with django framework.

```
# Create your views here.

import urllib2
import json
import urllib
from .models import Apiclass
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.conf import settings as config

def home(request):

    obj = Apiclass()

def postme(request):

    url = config.API_PROTOCOL+config.API_DOMAIN+config.API_SECURE_USER_URL
   # user_agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.5; Windows NT)'
    values = {'username' : 'waheeda@auction.com',
              'password' : '12345678'
              }
   # headers = { 'Content-Type' : "application/json" }


    data = urllib.urlencode(values)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, data)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)

    the_page = json.loads(response.read())

    return render_to_response("home.html",{'postme':the_page})
```

And ApiClass is under models/Apiclass.py

I tried many ways to import the model ApiClass
such as 
 - from app1.models import Apiclass
 - from .models import Apiclass

but it still does not work it gave me the errors like this

```
TypeError at /api
'module' object is not callable
Apiclass.py
```

I just comment all the implementation when ever I can create object that everything should be good.  Here is the Apiclass code

```
import urllib2
import urllib
import json

from django.conf import settings as config

# Create your models here.
class Apiclass:

    api_domain          = config.API_DOMAIN
```

Answer (score 0):

Your should have class `Apiclass` inside `models.py`. Also I recommend you to import from full module path .i.e `from YOUR_APP.models import Apiclass`

If you want folder structure:

```
models/
  __init__.py
```

and  inside `__init__.py` you could have `Apiclass` and import as `from YOUR_APP.models import Apiclass` as well.

Also make sure it is subclassed from `django.db.models.Model` if it touches database in any way as recommended below.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I did not touches the database just call to restful API. Here is the full implementation. 
import urllib2
import urllib
import json
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings as config
class Apiclass(models.Model):
    
    api_domain          = config.API_DOMAIN

Answer (score -1):

You haven't subclassed your ApiClass model correctly. It should subclass django Model

```
from django.db import models

class ApiClass(models.Model):
    pass
```

It's barfing because you are trying to call your class with this:

```
Apiclass()
```

but ApiClass doesn't currently have a **call** method.

Comment: Event I did from django.db import models

class ApiClass(models.Model):

Comment: here is the full project code implementation and this project I don't touches with database at all [link]http://dev.auction.com/chat/myproject.zip